# Ruby Rails Activerecord column traversing to check for null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I've got some data that gets returned by an ActiveRecord find_by_sql call. The data returned for one query looks like this:

```
    id UserId City      State   Zip     Country   Email        Phone   Age
    1  fred   Atlanta   GA     300909    null     me@me.com    null     35
    2  Sue    New York  NY     99801     null     Sue@me.com   null     38
    3  Bill   Dallas    TX     87654     null     bill@me.com  null     25
```

Then, I have another dataset with these values:

```
    id UserId City      State   Zip     Country   Email     Phone    Age
    4  fred   null       GA     300909    null     null     555-1212  null
    5  Sue    null       NY     99801     null     null     555-1213  null
    6  Bill   null       TX     87654     null     null     888-2121  null
```

Because we have optional fields, we don't know which data will be populated per scenario. I want to be able to list on a page all fields for which I have data, and not display the empty columns for each scenario. For the sake of this example, assume that whatever values are in the first row, will be populated for the rest of the rows in that dataset. As a side note, I also need to export these values as csv, and don't want the empty values there either. I've searched and searched, and haven't figured it out. I'm sure there has to be a way to do this in Ruby. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of records you can easily do this in ruby. If you have plenty of records then it can get slow and you'll probably need to use the database a bit more to check for null fields. Here is the basic gist of how to do it in ruby.

```
@records = Record.find_by_sql('crazy_sql_here')
if @records.any? { |record| record.email.present? }
  # Display row and heading
end
```

Depending on what library you use to export the data to CSV, you should be able to set which columns to use. Just skip over the country or email fields if there aren't any records.

Comment: Hi @Mario. How does this work with the second case where city, country, email, and age are all null? I actually have more columns that are returned than the example. Thanks for your help.